# Unable to delete list of Elasticsearch Indices

Tags: python, for-loop, elasticsearch

I have managed to create a python script where I can log into my Elasticsearch user and list all indices that have a doc count of zero.

However, I am facing a issue when it comes to deleting the list of indices. The script doesn't error, it just doesn't action the deletion.

I manually created indicies, with doc.count 0, in my ElasticSearch called test1, test2 etc.

The issue is near the end of the script. Even though I have added for loop to delete the indices, the output doesn't action this. It only prints out the output which is:

test1 0
test2 0
test3 0
test4 0
test5 0

```
params_dict = {
"h":"index,docs.count",
"s":"docs.count:asc",
"format":"json"
}

elastic_console = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/{url_ending}"
getRequestElasticSearch = requests.get(elastic_console, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD), verify=False, params=params_dict)
content = json.loads(getRequestElasticSearch.text)

# List indices with doc.count 0
for index in content:
    indiciesList = index
    collectdoccount = index['docs.count']
    search_int = int(collectdoccount)
    if search_int == 0:
       print(index['index'] , index['docs.count'])

for delete_index in content:
    if index['docs.count'] == 0:
       response = requests.delete(index['index'])
       requests.status_codes(response)
       print(response)
       
       if  response.status_code == 200:
            print(index['index'] , index['docs.count'])
       
       if response.status_code != 200:
          print (index['index'] , "index not deleted")
          print(response.content)
```

Any help would be a massive help.